# convert an object to array with property names too

Tags: javascript

I have an object like:

```
obj  {
property1: "8898"
property2: "2015-04-27 08:03:39.041"
property3: "27"
property4: "c10"
}
```

I need to convert this to an array.

My code:

```
var results=[];

for (var property in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       results.push(obj[property])
      }
}
```

Here i am getting only the values. I need to have the following result
`["property1":1,"property2":2]`  instead of `[1,2]`

I tried to append the property name but it did not have the desired result.

Comment: you can only do this by having an array of objects like [{'property1':1},{'property2':2}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
   property1: "8898",
   property2: "2015-04-27 08:03:39.041",
   property3: "27",
   property4: "c10",
 };
var results = [];

for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var str = property +':'+ obj[property];
        results.push(str)
    }
}
alert(results);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t9d5q6t5)**

Comment: this is what i exactly i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var results=[];

for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        results.push({name: property, value: obj[property]});
    }
}
```

Comment: this produces a array of objects: [  { name: "prop1", value: 1 } , { name: "prop2", value: 2 }, ... ] - looks nice for me :D
@user2010243, you should be more precise which result you want to receive..

Comment: i apologize if i have not communicated well. I got exactly what i wanted from the below answer by @ozil.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that you exactly want is here-

Considering the object-

```
var obj = {
    property1: "8898",
    property2: "2015-04-27 08:03:39.041",
    property3: "27",
    property4: "c10",
};
```

Once you run this function-

```
for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var str = obj[property];
        results.push(str)
    }
}
```

The array results will have values - 8898,2015-04-27 08:03:39.041,27,c10